# Python : Extract values from List of tuples

Tags: python

There are other questions posted for the topic but I have different issue. 
I have a list of tuples which I made by finding maximum three scores and corresponding values from two list:

```
score = [0.133961, 0.026456, 0.210888, 0.521684, 0.156776]
tone = [u'Anger', u'Disgust', u'Fear', u'Joy', u'Sadness']
```

and used

```
highest_three = sorted(zip(score, tone_name), reverse = True)[:3]
```

to get the output :

[(0.521684, u'Joy'), (0.210888, u'Fear'), (0.156776, u'Sadness')]

Now I only want to print in output.

```
Joy, Fear, Sadness
```

I used :

```
emo = ', '.join ('{}'.format(*el) for el in highest_three)
```

but this returns the score and I want to print tone_name only. Any suggestions ?

Comment: `', '.join(v for _, v in highest_three)`

Answer (score 1):

With less modification to your code:

```
score = [0.133961, 0.026456, 0.210888, 0.521684, 0.156776]
tone = [u'Anger', u'Disgust', u'Fear', u'Joy', u'Sadness']
highest_three = sorted(zip(score, tone), reverse = True)[:3]
print(','.join(v for _, v in highest_three))
```

output:

```
Joy,Fear,Sadness
```

Comment: what does _ stand for here. I am getting correct output but wanted to understand. Thanks

Comment: @RishabhRusia https://shahriar.svbtle.com/underscores-in-python might be helpful to you. _ has different meanings but this is convention for `not intended to be used`

Answer (score 0):

`highest_three` is a list of tuples and you just want the second element (`1st` index) in each tuple :

```
highest_three = sorted(zip(score, tone_name), reverse = True)[:3]

# get first element of each tuple and join using comma
emo = ', '.join(t[1] for t in highest_three)
print(emo) # 'Joy, Fear, Sadness'
```

Comment: So if I used t[0] will it give me only score. I am getting correct output from your method but wanted to understand.

Comment: Yes, because the first element of each tuple is the score and the second element is the tone.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the `zip` around, make a dictionary, and you'll have a much easier time.

```
score = [0.133961, 0.026456, 0.210888, 0.521684, 0.156776]
tone = [u'Anger', u'Disgust', u'Fear', u'Joy', u'Sadness']

d = dict(zip(tone, score))

result = sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True)
print(*result[:3])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print ', '.join([i[1] for i in highest_three])
```

The above will apply the `join` method to a list made up of only the second element of each tuple from the `highest_three` list

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, although other people already gave us good solutions.

```
from itertools import islice


emo = ', '.join(i[0] for i in islice(sorted(zip(tone, score), reverse=True), 3))
```